# Read hex or decimal from serial in Ignition

Tags: python, serial-port, hex, decimal, ignition

I have a serial device that returns 23 hex values. I read the values using `system.serial.readBytes('COM1', 23)` in Ignition. This returns `array('b', [-85, 112, 1, 18, -79, 0, 1, 116, -41, 2, -17, 10, 28, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])`. I know the values here are decimal from signed 2's complement, but how can I get the decimal value? For example -85 should be 171, or 0xAB in hex. I would prefer to directly read the hex values, but I don’t know how to do this. Any idea?

Comment: Theres no method on the serial module for reading hex. Even readStringAsBytes will still return a byte string, which you would have to cast over to hex.

Comment: Please convert your comment into an answer, so I can mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert them easily to a decimal value.

```
def signed2unsigned(val):
    if val >= 0:
        return val
    else:
        return 256+val
```